# Buffer Allocation With GetModuleFileNameEx

Tags: c++, windows, file, memory-management, buffer

I am currently trying to get the full filepath from my executable by providing a process ID, and this works "fine" in the since that its able to return some of the information needed, however for some reason it becomes corrupted and this can be seen when trying to return it as a plain string: C and if you iterate over each char and print each letter you get even more of a mess. Where is my current coding wrong when attempting allocate my buffer?

```
std::string User::getFullPath() {
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    if (hProcess != NULL)
    {
        GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, (LPWSTR)buffer, MAX_PATH);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    for (char i : buffer) {
        std::cout << i<<std::endl;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

[image]

How do I properly allocate the memory in this case to prevent corruption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the contents of your array are uninitialized if `OpenProcess()` fails. There is no need to use `OpenProcess()` on the calling process ID. Use `GetCurrentProcess()` instead, or simply use `GetModuleFileName()` instead.

That said, the real problem is not with memory allocation, but rather is that you are mixing ANSI and Unicode incorrectly. You are typecasting a `char[]` buffer to `wchar_t*`, which won't work.

You need to either:

- use a `wchar_t[]` instead:

```
std::wstring User::getFullPath() {
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    std::wcout << buffer << std::endl;
    return buffer;
}
```

- use `GetModuleFileName(Ex)A()` instead:

```
std::string User::getFullPath() {
    char buffer[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Yep... Thank you . This is exactly the answer I was looking for, Ill fix that right now.